# Binwidths/no. of bins for 2 histograms for overlaying them

Tags: histogram, graph-theory, networks

Should the binwidths for two histograms be same or no. of bins in both histograms be same when they are overlayed for comparison? or there is no correlation?
I am comparing histogram of centrality for two separate networks(graphs) by overlaying them.

Lets say, ranges for two histograms are: (0,0.5) & (0,0.8) and no. of entries are same= 900.
What I think is that, as no. of entries are same for 2 histograms,no. of bins=sqrt(900)=30 for both but as the ranges are different, binwidths differ.

So what should be the approach, same no. of bins or same binwidths?

Comment: What is the purpose of the comparison? I doubt that histograms are the right tool.

Comment: If the bins differ, then the problem is a mess as we need to try to worry about the effects of different bin schemes as well as how far the underlying data are the same or different. Any graphical issue should be soluble with transparency. Quantile-quantile plots are probably a better idea.